# How To Add Multiple Selects to an Existing IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq

I have a situation where the result set is 95% the same in 3 different situations.  The 5% difference depends on a given variable and thus fills in (or not) the remaining 5% of fields.

As a simple example, here is the result object that is getting returned:

```
public class MyResults {
  public string PropertyA { get; set; }
  public string PropertyB { get; set; }
  public string PropertyC { get; set; }
  public string PropertyD { get; set; }
  public string PropertyE { get; set; }
}
```

**Currently** I have a method where I build the results I have the following:

```
public List<MyResults> GetMyResults(int someParameter) {
  IQueryable<MyResults> query;

  if (someParameter == "A") {
    query = entities.Select(x => new MyResults {
      PropertyA = x.PropertyA, // Common
      PropertyB = x.PropertyB, // Common
      PropertyC = x.PropertyC, // Different
    };
  } else if (someParameter == "B") {
    query = entities.Select(x => new MyResults {
      PropertyA = x.PropertyA, // Common
      PropertyB = x.PropertyB, // Common
      PropertyD = x.PropertyD, // Different
    };
  } else {
    query = entities.Select(x => new MyResults {
      PropertyA = x.PropertyA, // Common
      PropertyB = x.PropertyB, // Common
      PropertyE = x.PropertyE, // Different
    };
  }

  return query.ToList();
}
```

This is a **Desired** way to do this:

```
public List<MyResults> GetMyResults(int someParameter) {
  IQueryable<MyResults> query = entities.Select(x => new MyResults {
    PropertyA = x.PropertyA, // Common
    PropertyB = x.PropertyB, // Common
    PropertyC = x.PropertyC, // Common
  };

  if (someParameter == "A") {
    query = entities.Select(x => new MyResults {
      PropertyC = x.PropertyC // Different
    });
  } else if (someParameter == "B") {
    query = entities.Select(x => new MyResults {
      PropertyD = x.PropertyD // Different
    });
  } else {
    query = entities.Select(x => new MyResults {
      PropertyE = x.PropertyE // Different
    });
  }

  return query.ToList();
}
```

This way the consistent fields on ALL results are the same and I only need to add what is different.

Is this possible?

Comment: This smells odd. Why can't you always set `PropertyC`, `PropertyD`, and `PropertyE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator as follows:

```
return entities.Select(x => new MyResults {
    PropertyA = x.PropertyA, // Common
    PropertyB = x.PropertyB, // Common
    PropertyC = someParameter == 1 ? x.PropertyC : null,
    PropertyD = someParameter == 2 ? x.PropertyD : null,
    PropertyE = someParameter == 3 ? x.PropertyE : null,
}).ToList();
```

Basically as `string`'s default is `null` if `someParameter` does not match the case for a given `propertyX` the properties value will be `null`. If it is, it will get the desired value

Comment: Well, excellent point.  This will work.  Is there a way to merge multiple `Select`s into a single query like I designed above?

Comment: @Grandizer - not in a nice way... Because when you do the lower selects what you are actually asking is to "update" but linq is less fitting for that. select is for projecting a new object. So can be done but will project a new object and set all the common properties again. You can maybe use the `Aggregate` method but it is not the purpose of it. I think this is the cleaner way

Comment: Understood.  Thank you @Gilad